# cannot convert to system.guid

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

we are using entity framework

---

```
private t_Market getMarketByCellsiteID(Guid cellsiteID)
{
    try
    {
        t_Market market = null;
        using (LiveLeaseEntities Entities = new LiveLeaseEntities())
        {
            market = (from m in Entities.t_Market
                      where m.OperatorId = (from o in Entities.t_CellSite
                                            where o.CellSiteId == Guid.Parse("53B7B160-20C4-4B60-948A-06570E6E3CBA")
                                            select o.OperatorId)
                      select m).Single();
            return market;
        }
    }
```

---

i am getting Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Guid'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should fix it:

```
private t_Market getMarketByCellsiteID(Guid cellsiteID)
{
try
{
    t_Market market = null;
    using (LiveLeaseEntities Entities = new LiveLeaseEntities())
    {
        market = (from m in Entities.t_Market
                  where m.OperatorId == (from o in Entities.t_CellSite
                                        where o.CellSiteId == Guid.Parse("53B7B160-20C4-4B60-948A-06570E6E3CBA")
                                        select o.OperatorId).Single()
                  select m).Single();
        return market;
    }
}
```

Two things:   You needed a `==` to do the comparison with `m.OperatorId`, and you were comparing it against a LINQ query, which returns IQuerable -- Calling Single() on the LINQ query executes it and returns a value to compare against.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with this comparison:

```
m.OperatorId = (from o in Entities.t_CellSite
    where o.CellSiteId == Guid.Parse("53B7B160-20C4-4B60-948A-06570E6E3CBA")
    select o.OperatorId)
```

You are comparing a `System.Guid` to an `System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Guid>`.  If you expecting only a single result, you could do:

```
m.OperatorId = (from o in Entities.t_CellSite
    where o.CellSiteId == Guid.Parse("53B7B160-20C4-4B60-948A-06570E6E3CBA")
    select o.OperatorId).First()
```